# OpenLayers 3 : put one layer in grayscale without changing other layers

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a tricky question concerning the possibility to put layers in grayscale with Open Layers 3.

I already achieve to put the whole map in grayscale using the possibilities of canvas element, like it can be seen in the examples proposed in the following discussion : [OpenLayers 3 - tile canvas context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872633/openlayers-3-tile-canvas-context)

But my need is slightly different from these examples : I want to give users the possibility to put layers one by one in grayscale, without changing the colour of other layers. The idea is for instance to have one background layer in grayscale with other data over it in colour.

Does someone know how such a thing can be achieved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ol.source.Raster](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Raster.html) is what you are looking for. Here is an [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/color-manipulation.html).

```
  var raster = new ol.source.Raster({
    sources: [new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'watercolor'
    })],
    operation: function(pixels, data) {
      // convert pixels to grayscale
      return pixels;
    }
  });
```

This enables you to manipulate the pixel data of arbitrary sources on a per-layer base.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be the right thing I need.
Thanks for the tip, I'm going to check it and share my experience

Comment: Hmm, a raster source can be used for an image layer (like in the example above), but I think it's not possible to attach a raster source to WMS or WMTS layer, is it ? My precise need concerns all types of layers.

Comment: `ol.source.Raster` works with all kind of tile or image sources, and WMS or WMTS sources are also tile/image sources.

Comment: Thanks for your patience ! but it seems I miss something.

1) In this example : http://test-ol3.alwaysdata.net/grayscale.htm I create a ol.layer.Tile based on a ol.source.WMTS, and then